# How to change dynamically 'onChange' attribute value depending on select value?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the value of my `onChange=""` in a TextField depending on the user's selected value in a ComboBox.

I have these ComboBox:

```
<div>
    <label>Wafer Type:</label>
    <select name="s1"">
        <option value="1"> First </option>
        <option value="2"> Second </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

when user select First:

```
<input type="text" name="lotNo" onchange="function1();">
```

when user select Second:

```
<input type="text" name="lotNo" onchange="function1(); function2()">
```

any recommendation on how can I achived to change the `onChange` value dynamically based on selected dropdown value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can execute a single onchange function, from there you can execute the function based on the value chosen. got it?

Comment: Hi @PradeepSambandam, I need to use 2 function for 2nd option on combo box.  i don't want to run the function2() on 1st option coz, it;s not needed.

Comment: Yes you can execute two functions in the conditional state if the value is 2.

Comment: Dynamic onChange function is very inconsiderable. You should try the way suggested by @PradeepSambandam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a single onchange function, from there you can execute the function based on the value chosen using a conditional statement. got it?

```
function mainFunction() {
    if (document.getElementsByName("s1").value == "1") {
       function1();
    }
    else if (document.getElementsByName("s1").value == "2"){
        function1();
        function2();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is:

```
<input type="text" name="lotNo" onchange="myClickHandler();">
```

You can call your specific function inside this handler, by checking the `select`'s value which has the `myselect` id on it:

```
function myClickHandler() {
    if (document.querySelector("#myselect").value == "1") {
        // first selected, call your function
    }
    else {
        // second selected, call your function    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add/remove the event based on the selected value like the following way:

```js
var inputEl = document.querySelector('[name=lotNo]')
function myFunc(el){
  var selVal = el.value;
  if(selVal == "1"){
    inputEl.removeEventListener('change', two); // remove the previous one
    inputEl.addEventListener('change', one); // now add
  }
  else if(selVal == "2"){
    inputEl.removeEventListener('change', one); // remove the previous one
    inputEl.addEventListener('change', two); // now add
  }
}
function one(){
  console.log('Funtion One is called');
}
function two(){
  console.log('Function Two is called');
}

// To work on page load
// Create a new 'change' event
var event = new Event('change');
// Dispatch it on page load.
document.querySelector('select').dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Wafer Type:</label>
    <select name="s1" onchange="myFunc(this);">
        <option value="1"> First </option>
        <option value="2"> Second </option>
    </select>
</div>

<input type="text" id="test" name="lotNo" >
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to do so. 
1)put input in one div and give it id.Now create java script onchange event of select control. now  in that put condtion that if option 1 is selected then replace input with your desize onchange events.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#s1").on('change', function(){
debugger;
if($("#s1 option:selected").val() == 1)
{
$("#changeinput").html("");
$("#changeinput").html('<input type="text" name="lotNo" onchange="function1();">')
}else
{
$("#changeinput").html("");
$("#changeinput").html('<input type="text" name="lotNo" onchange="function1();function2();">')
}

});

});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Wafer Type:</label>
    
  
    
    <select name="s1" id="s1" >
    <option value="0">Select </option>
        <option value="1"> First </option>
        <option value="2"> Second </option>
    </select>
    
    <br><br>
</div>

<div id="changeinput">
<input type="text" name="lotNo" onchange="function1();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the `onchange` attribute: a full-fledged event listener.

It automatically has access to the event that triggered it as its first argument (and we call this argument `event` for easy readability), and the `target` property of this `event` will refer to whichever element changed.

Whenever the `lotNo` input is changed, the listener invokes `function1` -- which subsequently invokes `function2` if the user has selected `Second` in the `s1` dropdown.

```js
const s1 = document.getElementsByName("s1")[0];
const lotNo = document.getElementsByName("lotNo")[0];

document.addEventListener("change", function1);

function function1(event){
  if(event.target == lotNo){
    console.log("function1 invoked");
    if(s1.value == "2"){ function2(); }
  }
}

function function2(){
  console.log("function2 invoked");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Wafer Type:</label>
  <select name="s1">
    <option value="1"> First </option>
    <option value="2"> Second </option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="text" name="lotNo" />
```